# how to pass extracted values with single variable in jmter using regular expression

Tags: jmeter

[image][image: using regular expression [![ from responsedata we need to extract testqa1 and testsampleqa1]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SeQp.png)

i want values if i put ${testqa 1}and${ testsampleqa1
} and so on
how to do that can u pls help me forthis issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regular expression field use this data:

a href = "test.(.*?).com/(.*?)/(.*?)"

In Template field, add $2$$3$

Leave the default value field blank.

To pass the extracted testqa1, use ${TestValues_g2}, to extract testsampleqa1, use ${TestValues_g3} where you want to pass them. If you want to combine the extracted value and pass it, then use ${TestValues1_g2}${TestValues1_g3} together, without space.

To capture all the values, use three regular expression extractor. In each one, use a different variable for storing the value eg. TestValues1, TestValues2, TestValues3. So, for extracting value from test.gmail.com, enter 1 in match no. column in 1st regular expression. For extracting value from test.bing.com, enter 2 in match no. column in 2nd regular expression and so on.

Comment: use ${TestValues_g1},${TestValues_g2} these two values where can i add ? means in regular expression ??

Comment: I need to capture all the values after the slash from the below url.

        a href = "test.gmail.com/testqa1/testsampleqa1"
        a href = "test.bing.com/testqa2/testsampleqa2"
        a href = "test.yahoo.com/testqa3/testsampleqa3"

    For above activity please use "Dummey Sampler" , after the extract the values i need to pass captured values with single variable as shown below.
    i.e test.gmail.com/${extractvariable} this my requirement can u pls suggest me

Comment: @Guruganesh Use these ${TestValues_g2} where you want to enter the extracted value. I have edited the answer, according to your doubts, kindly read it from the beginning..

Comment: tq so much rishikesh

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to extract all the values after the slash use the following regular expression

```
"test.(.+?).com\/(.+?)"
```

in the template field use `$1$2$` as we have 2 matching groups one for each matching group

If you want to extract all values you can use `-1` Match no  as shown below.

and Name your regular expression extractor as `TestValues` as shown below

[image]

Above expression will extract all 3 values and stores the values in

```
TestValue_1_g1 TestValue_1_g2
TestValue_2_g1 TestValue_2_g2
TestValue_3_g1 TestValue_3_g2
```

Group 1 stores the  domain name and Group 2 stores the value after slash

as shown below

[image]

use variables

```
    ${TestValue_1_g1} ${TestValue_1_g2}
    ${TestValue_2_g1} ${TestValue_2_g2}
    ${TestValue_3_g1} ${TestValue_3_g2}
```

where you want to replace the values   eg : to pass extracted variables

```
test.${TestValue_1_g1}.com/${TestValue_1_g2}
```

IF you want to extract a random value from 3 values you can use `0` instaead of `-1` match number in [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

and use `${TestValue_g1} ${TestValue_g2}` to replace, so you can use the following

```
test.${TestValue_g1}.com/${TestValue_g2}
```

Use this website for [testing your regular expression](https://regex101.com/) 
For more information on regular expression extractors [read this article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

Please let me know if it helps..

Comment: tq so much rohit